# Problema para configurar el bind9 en Linux(virtualBox)

Tags: linux, redes

Tengo 3 máquinas virtuales , una de windows, 2 de ubuntu (una hará de DNS y la otra de Servidor de la pág web.). (Están en local *sin salida a internet*)

Con la de windows tengo que acceder a una página web del servidorWeb pasando por el Dns.

Las máquinas se hacen pin, **si entro por la IP** **me muestra la página**, pero el **problema** está si pongo en el navegador w**ww.eduardo.com**

En el DNS tengo : en named.conf.local

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***   - En db.eduardo.com (creo que aquí está el problema)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

** Y en el servidorWeb

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y apartir de aquí no hace falta nada más, como ya dije si pongo directamente la ip del servidorWeb (169.254.31.252) se muestra la página.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente el cliente su servidor DNS apunta a la 253 y se hace ping y el DNS(253) Hace ping al SerWeb (252) Y el DNS (253) hace ping al SW(252)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Checka si esta incluido tu archivo `named.conf.local` en `named.conf`

Comment: Si, está incluido el named.conf.local , gracias

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema esta en que en el archivo db tienes que poner que poner en la penultima linea:
`www.eduardo.com. IN A 127.0.0.1`
`127.0.0.1` es una dirección que referencia al propio equipo, algo asi como localhost

Tambien en el named.conf(nose si tambien se podra en el named.conf.local) hay que pener o modificar algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Las rutas y la ip debes poner las de tu maquina

Comment: ya lo he probado y sigue sin ir... =(

Comment: El archivo named.conf creo que lleva otro include a `named.root.key` y no deben estar comentados

Comment: uso el named.conf.local para establecer el zone

Comment: Supongo que es lo mismo usar uno u otro